# Manifolds with special holonomy

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request

I would like to read Joyce's Riemannian Holonomy Groups and Calibrated Geometry but I'm not sure my background is enough.  I know algebraic topology up to Munkres' Elements, differential geometry up to Tu's Introduction to Manifolds and Do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry chapters 1-7.  Would this be enough or should I fill in gaps using other books?  If yes, I would like to have some recommendations, thank you.

Comment: Why dont you just try reading the book and see if you have any problems ?

Comment: I haven't read the particular text you're looking at, but your background is probably sufficient. The only thing that I would suggest is that you understand principal bundles with connection and associated bundles. It isn't absolutely necessary, but I think it will be helpful. Have a look in Natural Operations by Kolar, Michor, and Slovak. They do a really good job of explaining the theory.